# cannot set valid itemto QTableWidgetItem

Tags: pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to populate two different QTableWidgets. For the first one it works find, but for the second one, it won't actaully set the items to the QTableWidget.
In the second, failing attempt, it does successfully create the item (both type(item) and item.text() work fine and return the correct values). However, when I try to add the item to the table, it says that table2.item(row, col) is NoneType. The rows and columns are created correctly before setting the item though.

working attempt:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(self.fields[j].name())
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
table1.setItem(j,i,item)
```

failing attempt:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(typ)
item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)             
table2.setItem(row, col, item)
```

Neither can I see the difference between the two blocks, nor do I understand why it won't set the item to the TableWidget. Is there a geneal misunderstandng about how this works?

Comment: Without knowing more about your program, this is nearly impossible to answer. Assuming that `table1` and `table2` are of the same type and configured identically, then, if `self.fields[j].name()` and `typ` evaluate to the same string/QString, `row` is the same as `j`, and `col` is the same as `i`, both blocks are identical. Why don't you post a minimal working example, add a few `print` statements to check the variable's values and post the results here? Also the code with which you're checking the values might be interesting.

Comment: What is `typ`? maybe your `row` or `col` go out of range.. they are suppose to start from zero...